# Android Preferences Add Values from Database

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

One of the Preferences in my PreferenceActivity needs to get its values from a database. How do I add these values?

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen);

        ListPreference customPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
        **ADD_CUSTOM_VALUES_HERE**????? 
    }
```

Comment: Solution found at : http://www.craiget.com/2009/03/bridging-androids-listpreference-and-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the solution: http://craiget.com/bridging-androids-listpreference-and-database/

Comment: this link is broken :-(. do you have any sample.

Comment: @SamQuest: The link is working for me. The link in BahaiResearch.com's initial comment is also working.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i got it

```
listPreference.setEntries(entries)
listPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues)
```

where entries & entryValues may be

```
 CharSequence[] entries = {'Entry 1','Entry 2','Entry 3','Entry 4'}; 
 CharSequence[] entryValues= {0,1,2,3};
```